# Current executing procedure name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

Is it possible to get the name of the current Stored Procedure in MS SQL Server?

Maybe there is a system variable or function like `GETDATE()`?

Answer (score 173, accepted):

You may try this:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)
```

**Update:** This command is still valid on SQL Server 2022.

Comment: It's worth noting that the returned value is of type SYSNAME.

Comment: what to do for function not procedure? any idea? Please help

Comment: Still valid on SQL Serve 2012

Comment: Still valid on SQL Server 2016

Comment: Does not work for the session or global temporary stored procedures.

Comment: @ajeh No, I get a random table name when I try this from a temporary stored procedure.

Comment: @Elaskanator Provide your SQL like I did in the updated answer, we'll  figure out what is going on. And your server version too, please. ATM I have access to SQL 2012 and 2016 and in both the  result is NULL

Comment: @Buggieboy Please elaborate: why is it worth noting the type returned is SYSNAME?

Comment: See my answer below if you need working code for session/global temp procedures :-)

Comment: Still valid in SQL Server 2022.

Answer (score 91):

```
OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@@PROCID) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)
```

Comment: If you use this inside a temp Proc, it returns NULL, with or without the schema name retrieval.  1st proc is "normal", 2nd is temp, in this code:  `BEGIN TRAN
GO
CREATE PROC utility.TempProc
AS
SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@@PROCID)+'.'+OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)
GO
EXEC utility.TempProc
GO
ROLLBACK
GO
BEGIN TRAN
GO
CREATE PROC utility.#TempProc
AS
SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@@PROCID)+'.'+OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)
GO
EXEC utility.#TempProc
GO
ROLLBACK
GO`

Comment: See my answer below for session/global temp procedures ^_^

Answer (score 16):

You can use [OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174408.aspx)

> Returns the object identifier (ID) of
>   the current Transact-SQL module. A
>   Transact-SQL module can be a stored
>   procedure, user-defined function, or
>   trigger.

Answer (score 9):

In the specific case where you are interested in the name of the currently executing **temporary** stored procedure, you can get it via:

```
select name
from tempdb.sys.procedures
where object_id = @@procid
```

You cannot use the accepted answer in SQL Server to find the name of the currently executing temporary stored procedure:

```
create procedure #p
as
select object_name(@@PROCID) as name
go
exec #p


name
------------------------------------
NULL

(1 row affected)
```

Comment: Can confirm, tested in Enterprise 2014 in 2008R2 compatibility mode with session-scoping (double ##)

Comment: besides the fact, that it is right: Who would create temporary procedures?? :-D

Answer (score 3):

You can check for a `NULL` schema before getting the schema and name of the stored procedure:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@@PROCID) IS NULL
    THEN OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@@PROCID, 2) + N'.' + OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID, 2)
    ELSE OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@@PROCID   ) + N'.' + OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)
    END AS ProcName;
```

This means that you can get the right data even for (global) temporary stored procedures (click image to make bigger):

[image: names of non-temporary, temporary, and global temporary stored procedures]

```
USE [master]; --so we can test temp sprocs without cheating by being in tempdb.
GO

BEGIN TRAN;
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.NotTempProc
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT CASE
        WHEN OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@@PROCID) IS NULL
        THEN OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@@PROCID, 2) + N'.' + OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID, 2)
        ELSE OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@@PROCID   ) + N'.' + OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)
        END AS ProcName;
END
GO

EXEC dbo.NotTempProc;
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.#TempProc
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT CASE
        WHEN OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@@PROCID) IS NULL
        THEN OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@@PROCID, 2) + N'.' + OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID, 2)
        ELSE OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@@PROCID   ) + N'.' + OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)
        END AS ProcName;
END
GO

EXEC dbo.#TempProc;
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.##GlobalTempProc
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT CASE
        WHEN OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@@PROCID) IS NULL
        THEN OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@@PROCID, 2) + N'.' + OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID, 2)
        ELSE OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@@PROCID   ) + N'.' + OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)
        END AS ProcName;
END


GO

EXEC dbo.##GlobalTempProc;
GO

ROLLBACK;
```

Comment: While you're likely to know whether the stored proc is a temp stored proc or not when you're writing the code for it I think this answer shows clearly the difference between the code you'd need to add to a temp stored proc vs a normal stored proc.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but this is what I use.  It appears to always work.

```
BEGIN TRAN
GO
-- Stored procedure, function of trigger
CREATE PROC dbo.TempProc AS
    DECLARE @DATETIME = GETDATE()
        ,@Me VARCHAR(64) = COALESCE (
             OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@@PROCID, DB_ID())
            ,OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@@PROCID, DB_ID('tempdb'))
            ,'session'
        )
        + '.'
        + COALESCE (
             OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID, DB_ID())
            ,OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID, DB_ID('tempdb'))
            ,'SQL'
        )

    SELECT ProcName = @Me
GO
EXEC dbo.TempProc
GO
ROLLBACK
GO
BEGIN TRAN
GO
-- Temp Stored procedure
CREATE PROC #TempProc AS
    DECLARE @DATETIME = GETDATE()
        ,@Me VARCHAR(64) = COALESCE (
             OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@@PROCID, DB_ID())
            ,OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@@PROCID, DB_ID('tempdb'))
            ,'session'
        )
        + '.'
        + COALESCE (
             OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID, DB_ID())
            ,OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID, DB_ID('tempdb'))
            ,'SQL'
        )

    SELECT ProcName = @Me
GO
EXEC #TempProc 
GO
ROLLBACK
GO
-- SSMS or direct SQL statement
DECLARE @DATETIME = GETDATE()
    ,@Me VARCHAR(64) = COALESCE (
         OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@@PROCID, DB_ID())
        ,OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@@PROCID, DB_ID('tempdb'))
        ,'session'
    )
    + '.'
    + COALESCE (
         OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID, DB_ID())
        ,OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID, DB_ID('tempdb'))
        ,'SQL'
    )
SELECT ProcName = @Me
```