# get function name from itself

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a function, and inside this function, I want to get name of function. How can I do? I have try:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.func_test
--....
-- get name function
IF OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID) LIKE '%_test%'
SELECT @isTest = 1
ELSE
SELECT @isTest = 0
```

`OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)` seem support store procedure, not function

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034488/current-executing-procedure-name

Comment: I have try, but not correct

Comment: So you tried, and then what? Error? Incorrect results? If so what name was returned?

Comment: It return null, not name of function

Answer (score 0):

It's a [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/2287050/using-procid-into-a-user-defined-inline-function-resolve-to-an-id-that-doesnt-match-any-object) of SQL Server.

Maybe I use other way

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
 DECLARE @isTest INT

IF EXISTS (
SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = 'FUNCTION' AND ROUTINE_NAME  LIKE '%_test%')
BEGIN
SELECT @isTest = 1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT @isTest = 0
END

SELECT @isTest
```

Comment: The OP is looking for the name of the function that is currently being executed. Your scripts checks whether a function exists with a certain pattern. That's not the same.

Comment: just add my code inside your func_test function(replace everything just keep the signature to edit the function)  and execute.

Comment: Oh, sr, it not correct. I want to get name function itseft

Comment: you want the function name which you are executing itself?, like what @TT. told in the above comment

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you are gettinng,it works for me..

```
alter function dbo.uspo_test ()
returns int
as
begin
declare @name varchar(20)
set @name=object_name(@@procid)
if (@name) like '%_test'
return 1

return 0
end

select dbo.uspo_test ()
--output 1
```

Comment: The link in the OP's answer suggests that the bug only applies to inline table-valued functions. This information was missing from the question.